# Fourier series over non-symmetric interval

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Consider the function $$H:[-3,2] \to[2,2] $$
\begin{cases} 
      -2 & -3\leq x < \frac{-1}{2} \\
      2x & \frac{-1}{2}\leq x< \frac{1}{2} \\
      2 & \frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 2 
   \end{cases}
Determine the Fourier representation of H.

[image]

My question is: since this is not over a symmetric interval, how would I go about representing this function as a Fourier series? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For a Fourier series you do not need symmetric intervals. You can just scale an translate the trigonometric polynomials in such a way that they become periodic wrt. to any given (bounded) interval. If you do that you have to ensure that you also get an orthonormal system by introducing appropriate factors in front of either your Fourier integral or the series or both. (Like $1/pi$ in the classical case).

In your particular example just start out with $\sin$  and translate and scale it so that it vanishes at $-3, -1/2$ and $2$.

Alternatively, translate and scale the function which you need to develop into a series to $(-\pi, \pi)$, calculate it's Fourier series and translate back.

Comment: I'm just starting to learn this topic so I'm not really sure on how to tackle that. Since Fourier series do not require symmetric intervals, can I go about this problem the way I normally would? That is, finding $a_0, a_m,$ and $b_m$?

Comment: I don't know what hte way you normally would tackle is. The second approach I outlined is probably easier if you are lacking practise. So if you learned how to create a FS on, say, $(-\pi, \pi)$, transfer your function to that interval, i.e. look at $g(x):=f(ax +b)$ where $a, b$ are chosen in such a way that $g$ is defined on $(-\pi, \pi)$. Then calculate the Fourier series and translate back...

Comment: Do you have any books you would recommend I could use to further understand translations? I'm honestly unsure about how to do so. Also, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You don't need a book for that and I doubt that there is one dedicated to that topic. Just look at, say, $f(x-1)$ and $f(2x-1)$ for some $f$ (e.g. the one you depicted in your question) and draw their graphs to see what happens. You may need some time to figure that out, but that will be a good investment.

Comment: Is there anywhere I can see an example of this? I'm a visual learner and need to see things to understand them. Once again, thank you.